# Date binder culture

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, globalization

I have DateTime field in my model. The format in which I send date from frontend is `d.m.Y H:i`. And it is parsed ok.

But when I set US date format to be sent from frontend and set culture to `en-US` by typing `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US")` in `OnActionExecuting` method which is run before my controller action it says that date is not valid at `if (ModelState.IsValid)`.

My question is where in Asp.Net framework is set that default format is `d.m.Y H:i` and how can I change that default format? Does binder takes culture into consideration or it is always `d.m.Y H:i`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Vadim for your solution, but I found what is going on and solved it without custom date binder.

The problem is that parameter binding is done before the `OnActionExecuting` method where I put `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US")`, so the culture was still the default one when binding was done. And default culture is the one which is set in in Windows (system locale).

I changed it by putting `<globalization culture="en-US"/>` in `<system.web>` in `Web.config`.

So now binder parses US date correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the same issue with [custom data binder](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/605595/ASP-NET-MVC-Custom-Model-Binder) that I added to my project.

First, I add new class `DateTimeModelBinder`:

```
public class DateTimeModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var value = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);
        if (value != null)
        {
            DateTime time;

            // here you can add your own logic to parse input value to DateTime
            //if (DateTime.TryParseExact(value.AttemptedValue, "d.m.Y H:i", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out time))
            if (DateTime.TryParse(value.AttemptedValue, Culture.Ru, DateTimeStyles.None, out time))
            {
                return time;
            }
            else
            {
                bindingContext.ModelState.AddModelError(bindingContext.ModelName,
                    string.Format("Date {0} is not in the correct format", value.AttemptedValue));
            }
        }
        return base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);
    }
}
```

And then I add my bindeg in the `Global.asax.cs` on the application startup:

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
{
    ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(DateTime), new ateTimeModelBinder());
}
```